# Error building jetty with maven?

Tags: java, maven, jetty, terracotta

I'm trying to build jetty 6.1.26 from source using maven, i'm running the command "mvn" to build it however at the end of the build process i'm getting a terracotta build error.

The output is at: http://pastie.org/1908465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 58 tells you what the problem is:

> [ERROR] Plugin
>   org.terracotta.maven.plugins:tc-maven-plugin:1.1.8
>   or one of its dependencies could not
>   be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.terracotta.maven.plugins:tc-maven-plugin:jar:1.1.8:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.terracotta.maven.plugins:tc-maven-plugin:pom:1.1.8
>   from/to terracotta-plugin-repository
>   (http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/maven2):
>   Error transferring file: Server
>   returned HTTP response code: 503 for
>   URL:
>   http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/maven2/org/terracotta/maven/plugins/tc-maven-plugin/1.1.8/tc-maven-plugin-1.1.8.pom
>   -> [Help 1]

You get HTTP error code 503 (Service Unavailable). This might be an temporary state, try again later.